# C# EF SQL Application can move files when run manually but not when run by Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, sql, windows, entity-framework

My Error log comes as such:

```
2020-11-09 12:33:31.4463||ERROR|FolderClean.Worker.Workers.FolderCleanWorker|Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') |url: |action: 
2020-11-09 12:33:31.4463||ERROR|FolderClean.Worker.Workers.FolderCleanWorker|Error on File: \\alaris-prod\Batches\BatchTestingComponent\Renal\RenalBatch000002204 XAX\info |url: |action: 
2020-11-09 12:33:31.4463||ERROR|FolderClean.Worker.Workers.FolderCleanWorker|Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') |url: |action: 
2020-11-09 12:33:31.4775||ERROR|FolderClean.Worker.Workers.FolderCleanWorker|Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'from')
```

My connection string is simply:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=sb-sql;Database=AlarisSBStats;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

Where:

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                    services.Configure<EmailOption>(configuration.GetSection("Smtp"));
                    services.AddScoped(p =>
                    {
                        var connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
                        return new ApplicationDbContext(connectionString);
                    });
```

The application works as intended when ran manually however as a scheduled task I get the log errors above. It reads the value as 0. Not sure why its not working as it works manually.

Comment: Are you setting specific credentials when you setup the Scheduled Task or is this running as System?

Comment: Running through an administrator account with all permissions enabled

Comment: local admin or domain?  It looks like you are accessing a network share. are you sure that account that is executing this code can see network shares?

Comment: Yes, because it worked in manual mode as well and on the previous version it worked as well when the source and destination folders were network share drives. The issue now is when i am connecting to the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var connectionString = "Server=sb-sql; Database=AlarisSBStats;Trusted_Connection=True";
```

Hard coded it in and it worked!